# Will a split view controller enable the equivalent of 2 different tabs to function in tandem?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

Blessings!

I understand the basics intent of a split view controller as a navigational tool, as outlined in this tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/29469/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uisplitview-tutorial

But I cannot seem to discern whether the split view can enable me to run the equivalent of 2 different tabs in tandem?

I have a project which guides individuals to apply distinct tools and methods to the process of self actualization, including the actualization of latent human potential, and which is applicable to the common spiritual aspiration of cultivating intimacy with the moment (unfettered presence), but is also applicable to relationships, goals, visioning, taking action, shaping behavior and more.  It pulls from distinct methods including basic life coaching, spiritually aimed inquiry, psyche integration, shadow work and more.

The epic potential of this app is only discovered after using it for a month or so, because it lies in the radically unpredictable potential lying in the intersection of these methods and general aims.

As of right now, it will help me identify emotions (that might be otherwise repressed), welcome them, identify resistance to such, welcome that, let that go, and explore what arises then... in perpetuity (like a zen master or counselor or mens group facilitator might do)... BUT that process is also radically relevant to other aims... say visioning, or healing a relationship wound, or processing through resistance to being fiscally grounded and generous, for example.

As of right now the only way to integrate the two tools together is to flip back and forth in the tab bar, which aint bad, but which requires me to step out of the process and facilitate it, and the more I can eliminate that the deeper I can go into the experience...

SO... I need to be able to take one storyboard track (or path), and to combine it with another, in tandem... side by side... and I need to know if the split view controller in Xcode 5 enables such a phenomena to occur.  If not, does anything?

I could build this out by hand but seriously, it would be a massive unnecessary undertaking if such a thing were possible... to simply split the view, and have one storyboard sequence flow through one half of the view while the other storyboard sequence chills out, and then is taken back up, and then chills out...

You see what I mean?  One storyboard might ask me to heal my relationship with money, which (if I am broke), is gonna bring up a TON of resistance, which the other storyboard sequence can process and clear... if they are both available in tandem.

Help me out here!!

Also, this app is available to beta testers if you wanna get an experience of what I am talking about... I have space for 100 beta testers...

http://integralinquiryx.wordpress.com

Let me know your thoughts!!

-- Additional Questions I am sitting on --

I built the app for Xcode 7.1 target, is it hard to deploy for Xcode 6 at present?  Does this not involve creating an additional target?  Is there a guide to this?

I built the app for iPhone 3.5", learning 'what' constraints are along the way... and need to scale it to 4"... is there a way to 'add missing constraints' to the whole project all at once?  Is this a bad idea?

If you didn't guess it, its a virtual life coach app... and I am considering putting my voice in there and voice recognition so that someone could turn it on without looking at the screen, and it would be like talking to a life coach, (but limited to yes/no and specific answers to questions prompted)... is this possible?  Are there guides to this?

And the easiest... I need to set up BASIC conditionality.... if someone hits x button, it switches to mode 2, if again, mode 3... its a single button, across the app... that switches modes and reloads the correlative page... ( so if it asks a question in a way that doesn't work for you, you can switch styles and get it asked a different way, but then the ENTIRE process evolves in its style to mode B or C, etc, such that all of the questions to come are in the new style until you switch it again...

I know, this is probably BASIC conditionality, but where does it fit into the app?  Is there a guide for this?  Basic conditionality functionality?  Is this related to the view controller 'actions' function?  Steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Forget the split view, just use two container views on your main view. Each container can hold your custom storyboard and you essentially have one screen with two different sections. This would be your two tabs on one screen approach.

I think you meant you are developing for iOS 7.1, not Xcode 7.1. Yes you can deploy for iOS 6 but changing the base target SDK for your app, however at this point I wouldn't. iOS 8 is right around the corner and the vast majority have upgraded to iOS 7.x.

Turn what on without looking, the app? Apple does not allow that kind of functionality. You could use voice stuff once your app is open.

Comment: YES!!  The Container views solved my first problem... Thank you!

Comment: Turn on... Right... what I am looking to do is basically create a voice recognition protocol that will walk me/others through processes... it asks... do you want to look deeper at this?  (in a voice)... and if I am driving, I can say yes or no, and it will segue accordingly